# How to make custom search engine that on enter it goes to google and searches for what the user has inputed using html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

im not very good at html or javascript, but i thought it would be cool to make it so that every time i open a new tab, it is my own searchy thingy or whatever. The problem im having is making it search when I press enter but it never works, I have tried many things but none of them has worked. I honestly have little to no idea to what i'm doing even if I did take a whole class on html in high school. Here is my code.

HTML

```js
    const q = document.getElementById('query');
    const google = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='
    
    
    
    document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
      
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
         
         const url = google + q.value;
         const win = window.open(url, '_blank'); 
            win.focus();
            alert("test");
                  
        }
    });
```

```css
body{
background-color: black;
}
```

```html
    <section>
        <div class="searchBx">
            <input id="query" type="text" class="query" value="" style="background-color:white; color: black; border: none; border-width:0px; text-align:center "/>    

        </div>
```

Comment: your javascript is throwing exception, fix those so others can easily see what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work if you type it like this.

```
<style>
    .search-box{
        background-color:white;
        color: black; 
        border: none;
        border-width:0px;
        text-align:center;
        border:solid 1px #555555;
    }
</style> 

<input type="text" class="search-box" onchange = "search(this.value);" placeholder="Type your question?">    
<script>
    if(q==""){
        return false;
    }
    function search(q){
    let Link  = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='+q;
    window.open(Link, '_blank');  
    }
</script>
```

Comment: My bad!
the function line should be at first line:

Answer (score -1):

My bad!
The function line should be at the first line. please use the corrected code below:

```
   <script>
          function search(q){
                 if(q==""){
                        return false;
                 }
        
                 let Link  = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='+q;
                 window.open(Link, '_blank');  
          }
   </script>
```

Comment: Don’t post a separate answer if you simply want to amend your previous one - use the edit function.